# IronPython Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: unexpected token ',' when loading pickle module

Tags: c#, python, pickle, ironpython

When I try to use IronPython with script where I import pickle module I get an error:

> Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: unexpected token ','

This error occurs directly on importing:

```
import pickle
```

Is there a way to solve this problem? I read binary data, maybe there is another module to read this kind of data?

Answer (score -1):

You can apply this kind of solution except ironpython.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"C:\Users\kemal\Anaconda3\envs\movingDriving\python.exe";
var script = @"C:\Users\kemal\Desktop\testSendData.py";
var arg1 = "kkk";
psi.Arguments = $" \"{script}\" \"{arg1}\"";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
var errors = "";
var results = "";
using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
{
errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
Console.WriteLine(psi.Arguments.ToString());`enter code here`
}
Console.WriteLine("Errors: " + errors);
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + results);
}
```